# How to create class for read/write firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I create a model for reading and writing my queries in firabase and reusing them?

To read is what happens to do the query in my db firebase and with oncomplete return my result, I just need support to understand a bit the operation of the model in android.

to write I would also appreciate some idea of how to perform this method.

```
public class ReadFirebaseData {
        private DatabaseReference db;
        private FirebaseAuth mfirebaseAuth;
        private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
        private Gson gson;
        private SharedPreferences preferences;
        private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        private String jsonList;

        private static ReadFirebaseData INSTANCE;
}


   public static void readPlaces(final Context context, final OnComplete onComplete) {
   db.child("bdPlaces").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                   MyplacesList = new ArrayList<Myplaces>();
                   for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       Myplaces myplaces = snapshot.getValue(Myplaces.class);
                       String idPlaces = snapshot.getKey();
                       myplaces.setIdPlaces(idPlaces);
                       MyplacesList.add(new Myplaces(
                               myplaces.getNamePlaces(),
                               myplaces.getMyLatitud(),
                               myplaces.getMyLongitud(),
                               myplaces.getMyOpen(),
                               myplaces.getPlacesCategory(),
                               myplaces.getIdPlaces(),
                               myplaces.getDescPlaces(),
                               myplaces.getRate(),
                               myplaces.getImage()
                       ));
                   }
                  Log.w("Guardando:", MyplacesList.get(0).getNamePlaces());
               }

               gson = new Gson();
               jsonList = gson.toJson(MyplacesList);

              onComplete.onRequestComplete(e, jsonList);

           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

           }

       });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your getters that you want to use, I recommend you to use for your `Myplaces` model class, the following lines of code:

```
public class Myplaces {
    String namePlaces, myOpen, placesCategory, idPlaces, descPlaces, rate, image;
    long myLatitud, myLongitud;

    public Myplaces() {}

    public Myplaces(String namePlaces, String myOpen, String placesCategory, String idPlaces, String descPlaces, String rate, String image, long myLatitud, long myLongitud) {
        this.namePlaces = namePlaces;
        this.myOpen = myOpen;
        this.placesCategory = placesCategory;
        this.idPlaces = idPlaces;
        this.descPlaces = descPlaces;
        this.rate = rate;
        this.image = image;
        this.myLatitud = myLatitud;
        this.myLongitud = myLongitud;
    }

    public String getNamePlaces() {
        return namePlaces;
    }

    public String getMyOpen() {
        return myOpen;
    }

    public String getPlacesCategory() {
        return placesCategory;
    }

    public String getIdPlaces() {
        return idPlaces;
    }

    public String getDescPlaces() {
        return descPlaces;
    }

    public String getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public long getMyLatitud() {
        return myLatitud;
    }

    public long getMyLongitud() {
        return myLongitud;
    }
}
```

I assumed that all your fields are of type String and only `myLatitud` and `myLongitud` are of type long.

Comment: hello, thank you, if I have my MyPlaces class, like the one you gave me, I want to create a method in my windows that allows me to read all those classes.
I do not know if I explain I want to do something like the code I put in, but I'm a bit lost, how to implement it

Comment: I didn't understood you. "I want to create a method in my windows that allows me to read all those classes" Which widows and which classes?

Comment: ok now For example, I had my model where in my viewcontoller I could create a method that referred to a class with the query to perform, for example, I wanted to check my categories I called my method in my viewcontroller and in my class I had all the query then I returned the query made.

Comment: So a class like the one I showed you in my answer, can help you achieve this, right?